# How to get the creation date of a parquet file with python and pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, google-colaboratory

How to get the creation date of a parquet file?

They gave me the parquet files and I have them stored in my Google Drive for testing. I am using Google Colab with Python and Pyspark. What would be the correct command?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I haven't try on colab but with Databricks work in this way:

```
import os, time
path = '/local/file.parquet' # if you are on Databricks the adress could be dbfs:/mnt/local so you need replace to /dbfs/mnt/local/file.parquet
stat_info = os.stat(path)
print(stat_info)
print(stat_info.st_mtime)
print(time.ctime(stat_info.st_mtime))
```

Hope that works for you